# Trouble using Perl's select() to redirect prints to STDERR, method is overwritten in a library

Tags: html, perl, overriding, stderr

I´m trying to run a specific subroutine from a Perl library that prints a big amount of HTML code while executing. After doing some research, I found out that it is possible to use `select()` method to temporarily change `print` output to, say, STDERR, hiding it from the front end completely and then restoring it to STDOUT once the library has done its job.

Simple enough, but this won´t work for me. For some reason, someone created a method `select()` inside a critical library that has nothing to do with the above, but is a method to interact with our database. Therefore, whenever I try to use `my $filehandler = select(STDERR);`, I get the database method instead, which results in an error. And I can´t comment this method or remove it from the exported methods within that library without causing too much trouble on other scripts - including the library I'm trying to run.

I can´t even use HTML block comment to get out of this because the library also prints comments. Are there any other alternatives to run the correct `select()` method? Or any other alternatives at all to temporarily prevent HTML from being printed?

EDIT: For reference, my Perl version is v5.10.1 (*) built for x86_64-linux-thread-multi

Comment: Or https://stackoverflow.com/a/3673935/1207195

Comment: It's called a "file handle" (it holds a resources), not a file handler (it doesn't handle events)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As already mentioned in a [comment by toolic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45961095/trouble-using-perls-select-to-redirect-prints-to-stderr-method-is-overwritte/45961603#comment78880452_45961095), the most obvious solution is to use `CORE::select`. The `CORE::` namespace always gives you the built-ins.

```
sub select { 1; }

sub html {
    print "<html></html>";
}

open my $string_fh, '>', \my $string or die $!;
my $stdout = CORE::select $string_fh;

html();

CORE::select $stdout;
print "hello world";
```

As an alternative you could use [Capture::Tiny](https://metacpan.org/pod/Capture::Tiny), which really only does the same thing under the hood, but looks nicer.

```
use Capture::Tiny 'capture';

my ($stdout, undef, undef) = capture { html() };
```

---

As an aside, this might be a good time to refactor that `select` function and all the code that uses it, and to tell the colleague how much you like them. Also, watch [this talk from the Swiss Perl Workshop 2017](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4G5EaUNOhR0), which is relevant to the topic.

Comment: Reminds me of the time I needed to delete something from `%INC` and realized we had `use vars '%INC'` for some weird global hash stuff that was sharing product details between .pl files...

Comment: `CORE::select` worked like a charm for me! I don't think I need to import a library for this. Now, sorry if this looks like a silly question, but where is the output of `html()` going to @simbabque ? I thought I had to redirect it to STDERR, but it's not there. Is it being discarded?

Comment: @JorgeFreitas you can of course redirect it to STDOUT, but you don't have to. That would mean it would end up in your web server's error log, and your sysadmin is not going to like it very much. We are opening a handle to write to a variable, that's what the `\my $string` does. Your output is on that variable and you can even use it later on, or change it before using it.